# Trailing space to end \input| argument

Tags: pdftex, tex-core, shell-escape

Why do `\message{\input|"texlua ..."}` and `\message{\input|"texlua ..." }` give very different results?  Notice the extra space before `}` in the second case.

Minimal example to be compiled with `pdftex --shell-escape` below.

```
% Create an empty file \jobname.lua
%
\immediate\openout5\jobname.lua
\immediate\closeout5
%
% Only difference between \A and \B: a trailing space.
% Set \everyeof to allow \input within \edef.
%
\everyeof{\noexpand}
\edef\A{\input|"texlua \jobname.lua"}
\edef\B{\input|"texlua \jobname.lua" }
%
% Display the meanings in the terminal.
%
\newlinechar=10
\message
  {%
    ^^J^^J%
    \meaning\A % => macro:->Script file <jobname>.lua
    ^^J^^J%
    \meaning\B % => macro:->\par
    ^^J^^J%
  }
\bye
```

Comment: Maybe the `"` character is active here? Like it is when using [ngerman]{babel} for composing glyphs with a diaeresis (`"a` → `ä`).

Comment: @PatrickBergner No, it's not that as if you have for example a letter after the closing `"` then all is fine. I think it's to do with the fact that TeX delimits file names with a space, but can't quite work out why that gives the behaviour seen.

Comment: hmm in an unmodified TL2012 (cygwin) I get $ luatex --shell-escape in
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.2-2012062812 (TeX Live 2012)
 \write18 enabled.
(./in.tex
! I can't find file `|texlua in.lua}'.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This syntax is only available in pdfTeX, as for LuaTeX you are supposed to use the Lua interface. (That is true for several pdfTeX primitives. See most obviously `\pdfstrcmp`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say it is because the quotes are not argument braces, only quotes to guard e.g. spaces. If you run e.g. this:

```
\input "abc"d

\input "abc" d
\bye
```

You will get this error messages (assuming of course that the files don't exist):

```
! I can't find file `abcd'.
l.14 \input "abc"d
```

and

```
! I can't find file `abc'.
l.16 \input "abc" 
                  d
```

Also e.g. with xetex `\XeTeXinputencoding "utf8"cde` will lead to `Unknown encoding utf8cde`. You must use a space to actually end the input.

Addition after the discussion in the comments:

This means that the `\edef\A` case is processed probably along this lines: `\edef\A{\input|"texlua \jobname.lua"}\relax` => `\edef\A{Script file <jobname>.lua>} not found` => `\A` is `Script file <jobname>.lua` and `not found` is typeset.

Comment: I can see this argument, but shouldn't the space in Bruno's question terminate the 'filename', and leave `\input` with the same string to deal with.

Comment: Which space? In the case of `\B` the processing order is clear: The argument of `\input` is ended inside the braces. But in case of `A` things are more complicated. E.g. `{\input|"texlua \jobname.lua"}abc` leads for me (with `--enable-pipes` to this text in the pdf: `Script le test-utf8.luaabc not found`. Which shows that the `\input` looks behind the brace.

Comment: I think this only partially answers the question.  If `|texlua \jobname.lua}` is taken as a file name, hence `texlua \jobname.lua}` is run in the command, how come texlua doesn't just return a "no such file" error?

Comment: Ah! I think your last comment leads to an explanation: `{\input|"texlua foo.lua"}abc` => texlua issues the error message `Script file foo.lua}abc not found`, so in TeX we have the equivalent of `{Script file foo.lua}abc not found`, which leads to your `foo.luaabc` output in the pdf, but in my case leads to putting a mysterious `Script file foo.lua` in `\A` and typesets `abc not found`.

Comment: @Bruno: I think your message `Script file <jobname>.lua` is the first part of the "not found" message. The rest is probably eaten by the `\edef` (I really don't want to try to understand how it interacts with such an unsuccessful pipe ;-)).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  I think the rest is simply left in the input stream after the `\edef` ends, and is typeset.  So `\edef\A{\input|"texlua \jobname.lua"}\relax` => `\edef\A{Script file <jobname>.lua>} not found` => `\A` is `Script file` and `not found` is typeset.  Can you add something along those lines to your answer, should I, or should I add a separate answer?